# Adobe AEM CQ5.5 : Let Product Catalog match either one or second tag out of two tags

Tags: aem

I have a page in my catalog blueprint.It's `jcr:content` contains nodes `templates`, `target` and `filter`. In the `filter` node , i have a property `matchTags` set as multistring with a value of `xxx:products/pants`.

The Question is, how can I add make the Catalog Rollout create pages based on 2 tags, but instead of matching against both tags, create a page whenever a match of either tags is found.
e.g tags `[xxxx:products/pants, xxxx: products/shirts]` and i want pages to be created  on the same level in the content, if the product node i have imported has tag `xxxx:products/pants` **OR** `xxxx: products/shirts`

Comment , if i wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, this is not possible. The `matchTags` will match against all the provided tags, and if target product , does not have all the tags, it will not be generated. The only option is to create a unique tag for such group.